# An efficient way to store collections of unique enums with data

Tags: java, enums

In my current setup I'm storing my categorical enum (Defense) and value (Rank, also an enum) in a wrapper object.

```
public class RankedDefense implements Serializable {

     private Defense defense;
     private Rank rank;

     public RankedDefense(Defense d, Rank r) {
         defense = d;
         rank = r;
     }

     public Defense getDefense() {
         return defense;
     }

     public Rank getRank() {
         return rank;
     }
}
```

I then store lists of these in a data object (ScoutData). The same Defense will never be repeated in any of these lists.

The problem arises when I implement methods to organize the data from multiple ScoutData objects. I need to merge multiple lists of RankedDefenses **while making sure that the same Defense is never repeated.**

The only efficient way I found to do this was to repeatedly iterate over both lists and check. However, I'm not confident the method I used even works properly.

```
List<RankedDefense> defenses = new ArrayList<>();

for (ScoutData d : data) {
    //We need to compare every item in every list
    for (RankedDefense potential : d.getTeleopListDefensesBreached()) {

        for (RankedDefense listItem : defenses) {

            if (listItem.getDefense() == potential.getDefense()) {

                defenses.add(new RankedDefense(listItem.getDefense(), Rank.NOT_ATTEMPTED)); //TODO actually average the ranks
                break;
            }
        }


    }
}

return defenses;
```

I can't seem to figure out where to put the line of code that adds the RankedDefense if one with the same Defense isn't already in the list.

Is there a more efficient method to store my values that would prevent this iteration headache? And if not, is there a more readable and reliable way to implement the iteration code?

Comment: You need to look at `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`.

Comment: @EJP Thanks! That solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using EnumMap and changing my code accordingly has solved all my problems. It does exactly what I was looking for.